# Get column names in apply function with data frame (R)

Tags: r, names

This seems easy. But I cannot find an easy and quick solution to this thing.
I just want to run an apply function on a data frame - the result should show columnwise a message containing the column name. The rest of my command is working fine...

```
apply(airquality, 2, function(x) message(names(x)," has ",sum(!is.na(x))," cases.\n","NA values: ",
                                         length(x) - sum(!is.na(x))))
```

It does not show the name of each column. I suspect that this is because it works columnwise.. do I need to come up with my own function?
Thanks,
Nadine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would do it with `purrr::iwalk()`:

```
purrr::iwalk(airquality, ~ message(sprintf("%s has %s cases.\nNA values: %s",
                                           .y,
                                           sum(!is.na(.x)),
                                           sum(is.na(.x)))))
```

Output:

```
Ozone has 116 cases.
NA values: 37
Solar.R has 146 cases.
NA values: 7
Wind has 153 cases.
NA values: 0
Temp has 153 cases.
NA values: 0
Month has 153 cases.
NA values: 0
Day has 153 cases.
NA values: 0
```

Comment: I'll try it out :)

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the `names`:

```
lapply(names(airquality), function(x)
  message(x," has ",sum(!is.na(airquality[[x]]))," cases.\n","NA values: ",
          length(airquality[[x]]) - sum(!is.na(airquality[[x]])))
)
```

or maybe better in a `for` loop:

```
for(i in names(airquality)) {
  message(i," has ",sum(!is.na(airquality[[i]]))," cases.\n","NA values: ",
          length(airquality[[i]]) - sum(!is.na(airquality[[i]])))
}
#Ozone has 116 cases.
#NA values: 37
#Solar.R has 146 cases.
#NA values: 7
#Wind has 153 cases.
#NA values: 0
#Temp has 153 cases.
#NA values: 0
#Month has 153 cases.
#NA values: 0
#Day has 153 cases.
#NA values: 0
```

Comment: Yes this makes completely sense to me now. I should have iterated over names as input variable. Thank you very much!
But why does it attach after the message a result like this:

Comment: [[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
NULL

Comment: Because `lapply` returns something. That's why I also gave a `for` loop.